# MYSQL query problemidk

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like the picture below and I simply need to connect those 2 tables models and types on the left to look like the output on the right. Can anybody please help me with query?

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly a homework problem, and you haven't shown any effort.  If you've tried a query, can you post that?  Also, please include your table as _text_ directly in the question, not as images, and certainly not as image links (which may break later on).

Comment: Hint: join `models` twice to `types`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use JOIN in SQL in order to include data from multiple tables into your select. If you are new to joins, i highly recommend reading [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) post.

One way of doing it in your case may be:

```
select m.id, t1.name, t2.name from models m
left join types t1 on t1.id = m.type1
left join types t2 on t2.id = m.type2
```